# Averageif function equivalent for C++

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, average

I am a beginner to coding and am trying to shrink down a large, error prone piece of code. Pretty much I want it so

```
if (tileBlocked[row - 1][col] == true)
{ 
    add tileAir[row - 1][col] to averaging
}
```

such that I will find the average of the values in array tileAir only if tileBlocked does not list that area as blocked. I searched around and the only thing I found was Averageif, which is only for excel as far as I can tell. Is there any equivalent or some way in which I could decrease the size of this chunk of code and allow for better expand-ability?

Right now this is my current code:

```
for (int row = 1; row < 255; ++row) // Repeats for all rows, skipping the first and final row
    {

        for (int col = 1; col < 255; ++col) // Repeats for all columns, skipping the first and final column
        {

            bool check[4] = { tilesBlocked[row - 1][col], tilesBlocked[row][col - 1], tilesBlocked[row][col + 1], tilesBlocked[row + 1][col] }; // Creates an Array for testing what tiles should be ommited from the calculation

            if (tilesBlocked[row][col][0] == true) // If the tile being calculated is blocked, skip it
            {
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == true && check[2] == true && check[3] == true)
            {
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == false && check[2] == false && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 5);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == false && check[2] == false && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1]) / 4);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == false && check[2] == true && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 4);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == false && check[2] == true && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1]) / 3);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == true && check[2] == false && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 4);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == true && check[2] == false && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1]) / 3);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == true && check[2] == true && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 3);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == false && check[1] == true && check[2] == true && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row - 1][col]) / 2);
                tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == false && check[2] == false && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 4);
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == false && check[2] == false && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1]) / 3);
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == false && check[2] == true && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 3);
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == false && check[2] == true && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col - 1]) / 2);
                tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == true && check[2] == false && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 3);
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == true && check[2] == false && check[3] == true)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row][col + 1]) / 2);
                tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else if (check[0] == true && check[1] == true && check[2] == true && check[3] == false)
            {
                tilesOxygen[row][col] = ((tilesOxygen[row][col] + tilesOxygen[row + 1][col]) / 2);
                tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = tilesOxygen[row][col];
                tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
                tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Something Broke";
            }
        } 
    }
```

As you can see this is highly unexpandable and prone to error. In this specific example tileAir is replaced with tileOxygen.

Comment: Use function in c++ in case of repetitive code. In such cases error is fixated at one particular function instead of whole code.

Comment: i don't think it compiles. `tilesBlocked[row - 1][col]` seems to be a bool, then how can you dereference it for the third time:`tilesBlocked[row][col][0]`

Comment: @RishitSanmukhani How would that work with parallel_for (in terms of compatibility). There is actually going to be 6 different threads for each type of air. Also, any ideas on how I should setup that function?

Comment: for parallelization check out openmp.

Comment: @seleciii44 Ah, that is like that because I was actually in the process of changing the entire script to use a larger 4 dimensional array, tileAir. The first two dimensions are position in the world, the third is air type, and the forth is temperature. tileBlocked would become a 3 dimensional array where the first two are position and the third is temperature (if true while temp is 0, then pressure doesn't flow, while if true while on 1, then temperature doesn't flow. If both are true neither flow. So no, I don't expect this snip to compile.

Comment: tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
this part is really ugly and repeating. just use a function as proposed in the first comment.

Comment: @seleciii44 That is to set the edges of the array to 0. In a previous bit of coding a similar thing is done where the edges of tileBlocked is set to 1, to prevent air from flowing outside the bounds of the simulation. This is also why the code doesn't start at row and col 0, otherwise I would recieve an error for trying to use the array value tileAir[0 - 1][0], aka tileAir[-1][0]. -Edit- I would prefer to use PPL, I assume calling a function inside parallel_for would not cause any errors?

Comment: @JamesBlake all i'm saying is to put that 4 lines into a function such as: zeroupEdges(row, col). So that you don't write the same 4 lines every time. Also it makes it clear to understand.

Comment: @seleciii44 I understand that, you originally just wrote that snip of code and I was explaining it. -Edit- I would move this to a chat but I lack the reputation it seems.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, for any boolean expression `foo`, `foo==true` can be replaced by just `foo`, and `foo==false` can be replaced by `!foo.`

Comment: Thanks! I will use that in the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no equivalent to the Averageif in excel for C++. However the possibility of error was reduced and readability was increased by using functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your intent and your code, your loop can be transformed like this:

```
// Repeats for all rows, skipping the first and final row
for (int row = 1; row < 255; ++row) 
{
    // Repeats for all columns, skipping the first and final column
    for (int col = 1; col < 255; ++col) 
    {
        // If the tile being calculated is blocked, skip it
        if ( tilesBlocked[row][col]
            || ( tilesBlocked[row - 1][col] && tilesBlocked[row][col - 1]
            && tilesBlocked[row][col + 1] && tilesBlocked[row + 1][col] )) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        double avg = tilesOxygen[row][col];    // educated guess about the type
        int count = 1;
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row + 1][col] ) {
            avg += tilesOxygen[row + 1][col];
            ++count;
        }
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row][col + 1] ) {
            avg += tilesOxygen[row][col + 1];
            ++count;
        }
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row][col - 1] ) {
            avg += tilesOxygen[row][col - 1];
            ++count;
        }
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row - 1][col] ) {
            avg += tilesOxygen[row - 1][col];
            ++count;
        }
        avg /= count;
        tilesOxygen[row][col] = avg;
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row + 1][col] ) {
            tilesOxygen[row + 1][col] = avg;
        }
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row][col + 1] ) {
            tilesOxygen[row][col + 1] = avg;
        }
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row][col - 1] ) {
            tilesOxygen[row][col - 1] = avg;
        }
        if ( !tilesBlocked[row - 1][col] ) {
            tilesOxygen[row - 1][col] = avg;
        }
        tilesOxygen[0][col] = 0;
        tilesOxygen[row][0] = 0;
        tilesOxygen[255][col] = 0;
        tilesOxygen[row][255] = 0;
    } 
}
```